# VHDL how to use floor and log2 together

Tags: vhdl, floor

In the following code, if N equals 127 or 128, I always get BitLength=7 and BitLength2=6. Can someone explain this ?

```
constant N : integer := 128;
constant N_LOG2 : real := log2(real(N));
signal BitLength : integer := integer(N_LOG2);
signal BitLength2 : integer := integer(floor(N_LOG2));
```

I would have expected that BitLength is always equal to BitLength2 :

- For N=127, they should be equal to 6.
- For N=128, they should be equal to 7.

Comment: `Integer(SOME_REAL)` always rounds to nearest, hence it rounds 6.9887 to 7. So when N = 127, `BitLenth`=7 and `Bitlength2`=6. As for when N=128, they should both be 7. There might be some quirk in the float representation of 7 when it gets floored.

Comment: @Tricky I didn't know that integer rounds to the nearest. I thought it takes only the integer part. I understand the case for N=127. For N=128, how do you explain this "quirk" on BitLength2=6 ? Isn't it a bug ? How can I avoid this ?